# Making a list component in react and making each list item a toggle item, so that on click a picture shows beneath it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having trouble figuring out where i should iterate and where i should have the logic for the toggle. I have an App.js to hold everything, a listitem component file that where i want to build my list items, and in the toggle is where i make a state function and am currently trying to iterate. I am also confused by how i am getting json data. I dropped trying to fetch it externally and loaded it into a local file. How do i access the correct values and put them into my list?

I currently have this, where i can show one radio station name and channel. [Here is my current card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AM9Nj.jpg).
and [Here is my goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elQV1.jpg)

Links because i cant post images

-- [Here is app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfIA6.jpg)

```
import React from 'react';
import PostList from './posts/postsList'
import ListItem from './lists/ListItem'
import PostData from './data/postData.json'
import './App.css';
import Toggle from "./Toggle"




function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <body>
        <div className="card-trip">
        <div class="card-trip-header">
          <h3 id='header'>Stations</h3>
        </div>
          <div class="card-trip-infos">
            <div className='root'>

              <Toggle/>

            </div>
            <img class="card-trip-user avatar-bordered"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

-- [Here is toggle.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gp7RK.jpg)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ListItem from './lists/ListItem'
import PostData from './data/postData.json'
import { directive } from '@babel/types';

export default class Toggle extends Component {
  state = {
    on: false,
  }
  toggle = () => {
      this.setState({
      on: !this.state.on
    })
  }
  // render() {
  //   return (
  //     <ul>
  //        {PostData.radios.map((postDetail, index) => {
  //           return <ListItem/>
  //        })}
  //     </ul>
  //    )
  // }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
          <div>
                <ListItem/>
          </div>        
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```

--[Here is my ListItem.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIZ7S.jpg)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PostData from '../data/postData.json'
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";


export default class ListItem extends Component {
    state = {
        on: false,
      }
      toggle = () => {
          this.setState({
          on: !this.state.on
        })
      }

    render () {
        return (
           <li>
               <div>{PostData.radios[0].name} {PostData.radios[0].frequency}</div>
           </li>
        )
    }

};
```

--[Here is my json data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnRrn.jpg)

```
{

    "radios": [
        {
            "name": "Radio 1",
            "frequency": 99.23,
            "image": "https://dummyimage.com/400x400/3d43ff/ffffff&text=RadioOne"
        },
        {
            "name": "Radio 2",
            "frequency": 88.13,
            "image": "https://dummyimage.com/400x400/3d43ff/ffffff&text=RadioOne"
        },
        {
            "name": "Radio 3",
            "frequency": 89.99,
            "image": "https://dummyimage.com/400x400/3d43ff/ffffff&text=RadioOne"
        },
        {
            "name": "Radio 4",
            "frequency": 93.23,
            "image": "https://dummyimage.com/400x400/3d43ff/ffffff&text=RadioOne"
        }
    ]

}
```

-- index.css file

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen",
    "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue",
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Courier New",
    monospace;
}
.card-trip {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #2F2F39;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  width: 250px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: #797D8D;
}

.card-trip > img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.card-trip h2 {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
}

.card-trip p {
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: .7;
  margin: 0;
}


.card-trip .card-trip-infos {
  padding: 16px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
  position: relative;
}

.card-trip-infos .card-trip-user {
  position: absolute;
  right: 16px;
  top: -20px;
  width: 40px;
}
.card-trip-header {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ECAD60;

}

#header {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

#frequency {
  text-align: right;
}

#radioName {
  text-align: left;
}

body {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  border: 5px;
}
```

As i said above, i want to make a list component using json data, and make each item clickable to show picture, provided by the url in the json.

Thanks!!

Comment: Paste the code here, please refrain from using images when they aren't needed.

Comment: @Kobe fixed, sorry about that.

Comment: No worries, I'll have a look now.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the css too? I'll write a repl.it, so you can run the code

Comment: @Kobe Added it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should import the JSON data in the main component, and map over each result. You should pass the data of each loop through to the container, and utilise it there. You could then write an onclick event that will show the image. Check this [repl.it](https://repl.it/@Kozandmo/EnormousAdmirableConditions). It seems to me that you are new to react, so I would recommend learning hooks rather than classes.

Comment: Very new to react, thanks for this answer and the time you took for it! By container do you mean here app.js?

Comment: I mean Station.js :)